# Pandas replace only working with regex

Tags: python, pandas

I already found a workaround, but I'm still curious about what's going on:

When I try to do replace in Pandas like so:

```
merged4[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']] = merged4[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].replace(to_replace='.', value=',')
```

It's not working. I tried all different variants with Inplace for example. I also did astype(str) since the columns were float64.

However, when I do:

`merged4[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']] = merged4[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].replace(to_replace='\.', value=',', regex=True)`

It's working like charm.

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't use `regex=True` the method will look for the exact match of the replace_to value. When you use `regex=True` it will look for the sub strings too. So your code works when you use that parameter. 
Example

When you dont use the `regex=True` parameter, the replace method will look for the exact match of the replace_to value in the series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['k'] = ['YoYo.','mins.s.s','sos.s.','.','mama.mia']
df['k'].replace('.',',')
```

```
0       YoYo.
1    mins.s.s
2      sos.s.
3           ,
4    mama.mia
```

When you use `regex = True` it even matches the substrings of the series and changes the strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['k'] = ['YoYo.','mins.s.s','sos.s.','.','mama.mia']
df['k'].replace('\.',',',regex=True)
```

```
0       YoYo,
1    mins,s,s
2      sos,s,
3           ,
4    mama,mia
```

Comment: Went into whole word mode quietly, good to know