# Can I do str manipulation like this in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have used pandas to get my data looking like the dict in the code below.

I want to find all the salsa types, and put them in a dict with number of items with that salsa type being the dictionary value.

Here it is in Python.  Is there a way to do a thing like this in Pandas?  Or is this task where I should itertuples and use plain-ole-Python?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

items_df = pd.DataFrame({'choice_description': {0: '[Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Black Beans, Pinto Beans, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]]', 1: '[Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans, Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream]]', 2: '[Fresh Tomato Salsa (Mild), [Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]]', 3: '[Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Black Beans, Pinto Beans, Cheese, Sour Cream, Guacamole, Lettuce]]'}, 'item_name': {0: 'Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa', 1: 'Chips and Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa', 2: 'Chicken Bowl', 3: 'Steak Burrito'}})

salsa_types_d = {}

for row in items_df.itertuples():
    for food in row[1:]:
        fixed_foods_l = food.replace("and",',').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
        fixed_foods_l = [f.strip() for f in fixed_foods_l if f.find("alsa") > -1]
        for fixed_food in fixed_foods_l:
            salsa_types_d[fixed_food] = salsa_types_d.get(fixed_food, 0) + 1

print('\n'.join("%-33s:%d" % (k,salsa_types_d[k]) for k in sorted(salsa_types_d,key=salsa_types_d.get,reverse=True)))

"""
Output:

Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa        :2
Fresh Tomato Salsa               :1
Fresh Tomato Salsa (Mild)        :1
Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa      :1
Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot)  :1

---
Thank you for any insight.

Marilyn
"""
```

Comment: Why is your data like this to begin with? Surely a list would've been easier to work with than a string of `[` separated items?

Comment: Pandas, in general, is not really meant for intricate string manipulation. In any event, it's not like you lose any efficiency or speed by doing it in plain Python. Because pandas is built on numpy, and dtype=object is slow

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Comment: The data started here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv  Whether or not Pandas is good for intricate string manipulation was the heart of my question.  Did you see Bharath shetty's answer?  Now that is something to learn!

Comment: @MarilynDavis Hope you are ohk with new one line solution

Comment: YES Bharath.  And at least as readable.  Thank you so much.  You are really good at this and I'm learning a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this, @Bharathshetty.  I get an AttributeError with the one-liner:

File "./chipotle.py", line 28, in GetSalsaTypesOneLiner
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i.lstrip() for i in x if 'alsa' in i]))\
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

where the whole line is as you had it, I think:

.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i.lstrip() for i in x if 'alsa' in i])).stack.value_counts()

However, changing that last bit to:

.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i.lstrip() for i in x if 'alsa' in i]))[0].value_counts())

sets it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without using for loops one of the way is creating a separated df by `stacking` the columns and then `replacing the values` after that `dropping the values` which do not contain `alsa`. Then finally using `value_counts` to get the frequency.

```
new_df = items_df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
         .replace(['and', '\[', '\]'],[',', '',''], regex=True).str.split(',')
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i.lstrip() for i in x if 'alsa' in i]))[0].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Tomatillo Red Chili Salsa          2
Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa        1
Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot)    1
Fresh Tomato Salsa (Mild)          1
Fresh Tomato Salsa                 1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Exactly what I want to know.  Thank you so much Bharath.  I'm new here and my vote doesn't count.  But, this is the perfect answer.

Comment: @MarilynDavis Glad to help.  If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.

Comment: Why do we have to use regex=True in df.replace?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html says it can be list of str, regex, or numeric.  But a list of strs doesn't work.

Comment: `regex = true` replace the values even depth. i.e even substrings where as list of strs dont. If you dont pass that parameter then the method search for the exact matching of strings in a cell not to substring level.  For more info I have answered a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439506/pandas-replace-only-working-with-regex. Have a look. Happy learning.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you again @BharathShetty.  Your explanation worked on me when the doc didn't.  And, I deleted the correction comment.

Comment: Glad to help @MarilynDavis. Don't forget to upvote when you get enough reputation.